# TextWatcher not calling after first click

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, textwatcher

I have the **RecyclerListView** with **two EditTexts** inside. On each of edittexts I set OnClickListener, where I set CustomTextWatcher on current EditText. For the first click method OnClick works. But TextWatcher is not called.
For the second click everything works fine. Have any idea why this is happening?

in xml:

```
       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/edit"
           android:layout_width="64dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:clickable="true"
           android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

in adapter:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CardViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
...
holder.blocks.setOnClickListener(new MyEditTextClickListener());
... }

 private class MyEditTextClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
 public MyEditTextClickListener() {}
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.edit:
                callback.callback(EditText eT);
                break;
}}
```

in Activity:

```
 @Override
public void callback(final EditText eT) {
myTextWatcher = new MyTextWatcher(eT);
eT.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);
}

public class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
EditText eT;
public MyTextWatcher(EditText eT) {
        this.eT = eT;
}

 @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

 @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

  @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
```

Comment: Why not use text watcher directly in recycler view? Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37915902/7007823)

Comment: I need to use it in activity..@MalikKawee

Comment: where does `callback` belong to?

Comment: @MehranZamani, it's simple interface

Comment: which interface? and if you have empty `beforeTextChanged` and `onTextChanged` and `afterTextChanged`, how can you know that they are not working?

Comment: @MehranZamani, they are not empty. I maked they empty for example.

Comment: i think you should put your `addTextChangedListener` in your `oncreate` method of activity. because it doesn't matter where you set it. when text changes it will be called so you should put it where you are sure that it is set.