# Validate RecyclerView content

Tags: android, validation, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I think there is no need to repeat the exact description of how my RecyclerView is set. This is described here: [Android - RecyclerView with various dynamic content, different for each item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449794/android-recyclerview-with-various-dynamic-content-different-for-each-item/)

In short, my Recycler View may contain various controls, like edit text, spinner, etc. Then, recyclerview is placed in Activity layout, always expanded with nested scroll view as its parent. When user hit "Confirm" button in my activity, recycler view's content should be validated - for example, if any particular item contains textview that needs to be nonempty, activity should not be finished and standard error mark inside that particular edit text should be shown.

Inside my recycler view, I created `validate` method and it should return `true` or `false` so I will know validation result. However, I don't know how to access particular recyclerview item's content from adapter, this is my method (in this case, edit text control with type set to email):

```
public boolean validate()
    {
        for(Object item : items)
        {
            Parameter p = (Parameter)item;

            switch (p.type)
            {
                case Parameter.EMAIL_PARAM:
                {

                    String email = ((EmailParameter)p).value;
                    /*validate email here, if invalid, return
                     false and set error indicatior for corresponding 
                     recyclerview item*/

                }
            }
        }


        return true;
    }
```

`items` is `List<Object>` and it contains all recyclerview items with various actual types, each type determines particular recylerview content rendered. When user changes particular item's control, the corresponding item from `items` will be updated respectively, so when `validate`  called, all items contain fresh data (in case of `EmailParameter` it will be `value` field already set to text typed in edit text control).

As I can validate final values easily, I don't know, how to update corresponding recycler view item control to show an error.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Post your Parameter class, if it is a custom class you've created, I am going to assume you have a unique id associated with the parameter stored in the class. I would suggest creating a new common field in the class to set error and display it on individual items in recyclerview by calling notifyItemChanged / notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: Yes, actually this is how I solved that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution - use `notifyDatasetChanged`:

```
public boolean validate()
    {
        boolean allValid = true;

        for(Object item : items)
        {
            Parameter p = (Parameter)item;

            switch (p.type)
            {
                case Parameter.EMAIL_PARAM:
                {

                    String email = ((EmailParameter)p).value;
                    /*validate email here, if invalid, return
                     false and set error indicatior for corresponding 
                     recyclerview item*/

                    p.errorMessage = valid ? null:"Email is incorrect";
                    allValid &= valid;

                    break;

                }
               /*All remaining parameter types validaion*/
            }



        }


         if(!allValid) this.notifyDataSetChanged();
         return allValid;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that library is what you need https://github.com/Link184/KidAdapter

Here is a short example how you can validate data:

```
val adapter : TypedKidAdapter = recyclerView.setUp {
    withViewType {
        withItems(mutableListOf("one", "two"))
        withLayoutResId(android.R.layout.list_content)
        withContentComparator<String> { oldObject, newObject ->
            insertNewViewType(newItems)
            oldObject.compareTo(newObject)
        }
        withItemsComparator<String> { oldObject, newObject ->
            oldObject.equals(newObject).also {
                updateItemsFromViewType(someNewItems)
            }
        }
        bind<String> {
            //ui logic
        }
    }

    withViewType {
        //another viewtype config
    }
}

fun insertNewViewType(newItems: MutableList<Any>) {
    adapter restructure {
        insertTop {
            withItems(newItems)
            withLayoutResId(android.R.layout.list_content)
            withItemsComparator<Any> {
                ...
            }
            bind<Any> { 
                //UI logic
            }
        }
    }
}

fun updateItemsFromViewType(newItems: String) {
    adapter update {
        insertBottom(newItems)
    }
}
```